# Is modifying a mutable member of a const object valid?

Tags: c++, constants, mutable

In C++ you can now have `mutable` members. This adds a layer of "logical const" to the language. How do these relate to read only data - will having a `mutable` member prevent a const class from being put into a `.rodata` section?

```
class Foo {
    mutable int bar;

public:
    Foo(): bar(0) {}
    void set(int x) const { bar = x; }
};

// Can this be in a read-only section?
const Foo foo;

int main(void)
{
    // Is this well-defined?
    foo.set(5);
}
```

Comment: That's what `mutable` is for O_o As you seem to know already.

Comment: Yes. How else could `mutable` work?

Comment: Why would an object that is only logically const be in the `.rodata` section?

Comment: @Deduplicator it could essentially be an automatic const-cast.  I thought it would be strange but it also seems to go against C/C++ to have logical const as everything else is bitwise.

Comment: I've used `mutable` only once that I can remember - it was to add an internal cache to a class. The cache needed to be updated even though the object itself was `const`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are allowed to modify mutable members of const objects, this is covered in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `7.1.1` *Storage class specifiers* which says:

> The mutable specifier on a class data member nullifies a const
>   specifier applied to the containing class object and permits
>   modification of the mutable class member even though the rest of the
>   object is const (7.1.6.1).

The [Technical Report on C++ Performance](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/18015.html)  section `7.1` *ROMability* covers the cases when a compiler could put data in read-only memory. In this case that would not be possible since it is clearly not immutable:

> The subject of ROMability therefore has performance application to all
>   programs, where immutable portions of the program can be placed in a
>   shared, read-only space.

Comment: Thanks, so a mutable member transforms a whole class to "logical const" rather then the traditional "bitwise const" of C/C++.

Comment: @KevinCox You've been grossly misled if anyone told you that constness was about physical read-only memory. There never was a "bitwise const" meaning, constness is only a logical / conceptual thing that is enforced by the compiler. The concept of "bitwise const" is closest to what the standard would refer to as constant-expressions and literal types (which is also what is informally described in that Performance-TR). Put simply, constant-expressions are ROMable, everything else isn't. Without `constexpr` specifiers, compilers can still try to form constant-expressions but are not required to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes `mutable` member can be modified in const method and most probably will remove that object ROMability. There are also other requirement to make an instance of class ROMable. Details can be found in [Techincal Report on C++ Perfomance](http://www.stroustrup.com/Performance-TR.pdf) chapter 7 and [here](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=218)